# Stream "on the fly" from matrix

Tags: java, array, iterator, stream

I want to produce a `Stream<Pixel>` from a `Pixel[][]`. My code for this is extremely verbose so I suspect I am doing something bad.

Please provide me some advice on how to make my code shorter and cleaner.

```
private Stream<Pixel> stream() {
    Iterable<Pixel> iterable = new Iterable<Pixel>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Pixel> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<Pixel>() {
                private int row = 0;
                private int col = 0;

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return row < height && col < width;
                }

                @Override
                public Pixel next() {
                    Pixel pixel = pixels[row][col];

                    if (col == width - 1) {
                        col = 0;
                        row++;
                    } else {
                        col++;
                    }

                    return pixel;
                }

                @Override
                public void remove() {
                    throw new RuntimeException("nope");
                }
            };
        }
    };

    return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
}
```

For example, in Python I could do something like:

```
def stream():
    for row in pixels:
        for pixel in row:
            yield pixel
```

Which is certainly much more concise and understandable.

Comment: Do you need someone to review your existing code? Anyway, check out the similar question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601036/stream-from-two-dimensional-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course use the `Arrays.stream()` (twice, because it's a 2D array)

Something along these lines:

```
private Stream<Pixel> stream() {
  return Arrays.stream(pixels).flatMap(Arrays::stream);
}
```